# как составить простое регулярное выражение php?

Tags: php

$text = " Раздел I ВСТУПЛЕНИЕ Раздел II ОГЛАВЛЕНИЕ";

тоесть меняется римские символы и название

создать массив
explode('разделить по разделам', $text);

Comment: и что вы хотите тут вычленить из него?

Comment: нужно разделение сделать массив создать по разделителю

Comment: я видимо догадаться должен, что именно разделить и от чего?

Comment: создать массив 
$text = "
Раздел I ВСТУПЛЕНИЕ

Раздел II ОГЛАВЛЕНИЕ"
explode('разделить по разделам', $text);

Comment: я вам в предыдущем вопросе предложил разделить по двойнопу переносу строк. чем оно не подошло?

Comment: по какому разделителю? В вопросе никакой разделитель не упоминается

Comment: @Эникейщик `^Раздел\s+[IVXL]+` по такому видимо

Comment: teran вот это более подходит